# Official docker images with no tag. What they are then?

Tags: docker

I know what tags like `buster` and `bullseye` mean, but what if there's no tag to identify the OS?

For instance, the official Python image on Docker Hub has `python:latest` and `python:slim`. How to understand what operating system (Ubuntu, Debian, Windows 10, Windows 2019, etc) those images are based on, other than building a container from them?

Comment: No it doesn't at all.

Comment: Docker images don't contain an OS. Your question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @HansKilian So what tags like ```bullseye``` mean?

Comment: It means that the libraries, shell and utilities in the image come from Bullseye. But it's not mandatory to have any libraries in an image and it's quite possible to base your image on `scratch`, i.e. an empty image if you have a self-contained executable.

Comment: @HansKilian I didn't ask about those special circumstances. I asked, for Python image, if there's no ```bullseye``` or ```buster``` tags, how I'm going to find out those libraries, shell and utilities are coming from Debian, Ubuntu or what.

Comment: Like I said in my answer that you recommended that I delete, the tags aren't used to specify what the image contains. They're used to indicate what should happen to your image when the python image is updated.

Comment: @HansKilian ```buster``` means the image is based on Debian 10.13. Right? Not Arch or Alpine, correct? And not even Debian 10.14 which is ```bullseye```?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I can't remember the version numbers in my head. But what helped me is thinking about why the same image has multiple tags. Why does it make sense that I can refer to the same image using either `bullseye`, `3`, `3.11`, `3.11.2`, `3.11.2-bullseye` or `latest`? It makes sense if you use them to indicate what should happen when a new version of the python image is made.

Comment: @HansKilian So for an image with none of those tags (like ```python:latest``` or ```python:slim```, how do I know what's the shell? Is it ```sh``` or ```bash```? Where the utilities are coming from because ```alpine``` is very different from ```debian```?

Comment: The way I usually do it is to go to the image page. Often they list the tags. Search for `latest` and then you can see what other tags you can use to refer to that version of the image. The Python image page is here: https://hub.docker.com/_/python

Comment: @HansKilian That's where my question is coming from. The ```latest``` tag of Python says ```linux/386``` or ```windows/amd64```. I think we have more than 200 linux distros based on RPM or Debian. As for Windows, we have 2016 and 2019 (and of course 10 and 11). Looks like the only way to find out is to build the image and then investigate it.

Comment: Did you note the link on https://hub.docker.com/_/python to ["What's the difference between 'Shared' and 'Simple' tags?" in the FAQ.](https://github.com/docker-library/faq#whats-the-difference-between-shared-and-simple-tags) ?

Comment: @Luuk Read the original post and all comments.

Comment: @HansKilian Let me put it this way: assume I have ```FROM python:latest``` in my Dockerfile. Next I want to install a package. Which package manager should I use? ```apt``` or ```yum``` ?

Comment: For the python image, you should use `apt`. It sounds like you're trying to find a way to figure out what to use based on the tag and there isn't one. Things you can do is to find the Dockerfile and see what it's built on or maybe do `docker run --rm python:latest cat /etc/os-release` to see what that tells you.

Comment: @HansKilian I found the answer and posted it. I suggest you read more about Docker specially the difference between Docker image and Dockerfile ;)

Comment: @OmidShojaee Thank you for the suggestion, but I think I know enough. Here is the Dockerfile for `python:latest` where you can see what they use as the base image: https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/5d908b0477c003712550c84ac4d133367b912f78/3.11/bookworm/Dockerfile :)

Comment: @HansKilian Exactly! That's what I asked originally! A docker image is a stripped-down OS because Python, Postgres, Node, etc cannot run in the void!

Answer (score 0):

The tag is just a label for the image, it not directly related to the OS. It could be a semver like `1.4.2` it could be a branch name like `develop`, it could be an OS name but usually isnt. Them same tag can be built for multiple OS versions to allow `python:latest` to be run on windows or linux and docker will get the right OS version.

You can see by searching on dockerhub and looking at `python:latest` this tag supports a wide number of OS

[image]

Comment: Tags like ```bullseye``` and ```buster``` are directly related to the OS. And my question is how to determine the OS if not specified. For example in your screenshot what ```linux/386``` or ```windows/amd64``` mean? What flavour of Linux? What version of Windows?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to click on a tag and then check the image hierarchy. It shows what OS is the image is based on.

For example, the "latest" Python image is based on Debian 12.

[image]

Or the image of MySQL is based on OracleLinux:

[image]